# Action bar text and button color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Nexus7, 1280x800, Android 4.4.2
: [Click to view image 1](http://i.hizliresim.com/Pv9Og9.png)

Nexus S, 400x800, Android 4.0.4
: [Click to view image 2](http://i.hizliresim.com/AZayaL.png)

How to set white text and white button color? My style.xml file. Note: I've disabled the application icon

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
 <!-- IMPORTANT! Main activity, remove app icon. -->
  <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
  <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
 <!-- Main activity, remove action bar. -->
 <style name="BarYok" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Theme.AppCompat.Light` assumes the action bar is a light color, hence the dark text. If you instead are using a darker color action bar and want light text, you should use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as your `parent` theme.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as an answer to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.